# Started SQL Server Service on cluster remotely but cluster resource is offline

Tags: windows, powershell, service, failovercluster

I have an issue while I start SQL Server service remotely using powershell. The Service is hosted on a cluster as a cluster instance. I start the service with service name, not cluster resource name. So, I am able to bring the service online and connect to the instance, however, the cluster administrator shows the resource is offline until I bring it online. Why is this problem. Why is cluster not able to detect service status.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think starting the `SQL Server` service will bring the SQL Cluster Resource online. Because you are only attempting to start the SQL Svcs Locally. It is as good as starting the services using service control manager.

You should rather be using `Start-ClusterResource -Name <SQLClusterResourceName>`

Comment: But, if I go manually start SQL Service in configuration manager, it brings the cluster resource online.

Comment: Service Control Manager is different from SSCM. They both work differently. SCM is a Windows component. It will not go beyond starting the service. SSCM is a SQL tool and I am pretty sure it is doing more checks than the SCM